# How to export a Python list to MS Word?

Tags: python, list, docx

I have a list in Python which is split into multiple lists of 1 row and 3 columns. I need to export this into MS Word.

I have tried converting it to a data frame and using the docx library this does not work.
Also tried adding a new paragraph using doc.add_paragraph and it will not output the split out list.

Example of how the list looks like:

```
[x,y,z,1,2,3]

[x,y,z,4,5,6]
```

Each list has a heading (which is the same for all and some values associated with it)

The output I am after in MS Word is:

```
x y z
1 2 3


x y z 
4 5 6
```

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi there, I've tried using ```doc.add_paragraph(print(list))``` , then tried to turn into a dataframe ```doc.add_paragraph(['list'])``` and tried ```list = (list.astype(str)  + "\n       ").tolist()```

Comment: Please include your attempts, results in the question. Also if you are using any package, include the package name with version number. Please go through [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for sending the link! I'm a newbie so its very helpful. Code example: ```import pandas as pd
import docx

raw_data = {'X': ['1','2','3'], 
        'Y': ['4','5','6'], 
        'Z': ['7','8','9']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
df
    
l = [df.iloc[[i], :] for i in range(len(df))]   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write
doc.add_paragraph(print(list))
didn't work. 
I don't think you can pass in a print statement. Have you tried passing a simple string?

Instead of saying 'it didn't work' please provide error messages or reasons why it doesn't work. 
Otherwise it 's hard to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I created a string from the list and passed it as a string to the doc.add_paragraph() function and it prints correctly.

Comment: You're welcome. If it answers your question please mark it as answered, so others know it is answered